# Game Programming - Map Clipping

Tags: clipping

I have a sprite that moves at a velocity of 1,1 across a background image. I want to draw the background image with the sprite always at the centre as the background is about 2000x2000. My problem is as the sprite moves the background repositions but its as if the sprite is moving at 2,2 and the background is moving at 1,1. So the sprite gradually moves off the screen even though the sprite is moving at 1,1 and the background surely cant be moving slower than that?

To update the velocity of sprite:

```
    Point car = new Point(
            ((GameBoard) findViewById(R.id.the_canvas)).getCarX(),
            ((GameBoard) findViewById(R.id.the_canvas)).getCarY());
    car.x = car.x + carVelocity.x;
    car.y = car.y + carVelocity.y;
    ((GameBoard) findViewById(R.id.the_canvas))
            .setCarLocation(car.x, car.y);
```

Definition of velocity:

```
    carVelocity = new Point(1, 1);
```

Drawing the map around the car:
    public void drawMap(Canvas canvas) {

```
    if (car.x > 0) {

        int x = car.x - getWidth() / 2;
        int y = car.y - getHeight() / 2;

        Bitmap clipArea = Bitmap.createBitmap(map, x, y, getWidth(),
                getHeight());
        canvas.drawBitmap(clipArea, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

So i can't see why the car would move off the screen as it looks to me as the background should always draw with the car in the middle of the screen. I have put logging on both and they both increase by 1 on the X and Y each time.

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT:

Hi here is the drawing part for the car:

public void drawCar(Canvas canvas) {

```
if (car.x > 0) {
    m.reset();
    m.postTranslate((float) (getWidth() / 2), (float) (getHeight() / 2));
    m.postRotate(carRotation,
            (float) (getWidth()/2 + carBounds.width() / 2.0),
            (float) (getHeight()/2 + carBounds.height() / 2.0));
    canvas.drawBitmap(carBitmap, m, null);
}
```

If I draw it like the above then it draws in the centre (im using this while i test) but ofcourse i can never reach the edge of the map as once i am at the end of the bitmap it stays in the middle of the screen. Once i change to car.x and car.y instead of getWidth()/2 it gradually disspears off the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Are you drawing the car at the car's X/Y position or in the center of the screen? I think your background calculation might be fine, but the car is moving off screen because you're changing the position you're drawing it at.

A background doesn't really move, right? I think you should think about it as the car moving 1,1 (or whatever velocity) and the background is not moving at all, you just calculate what section of the background the car is in. Another way to think about this is that the car's screen position is fixed (in the center, not moving), and the background is moving at -car.velocity.

You should also consider tagging your questions with the language you're working in if you're including code samples (C#?).

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting to happen. When you get to the edge of the background bitmap, you can't continue to "move" in that direction and keep the map in the same place. Are you wanting the background to repeat?

Comment: No I want to use car.x and car.y so i can reach the edge, this works! but when I do this the car moves faster than the camera follows. So imagine the camera is moving at 1,1 and the car is moving at 2,2 so the camera can not follow the car quick enough and the car disappears off the screen. This I do not understand as I should be clipping the background at car.x - getWidth()/2 so the camera should centre around the car right? At the start this is true but once the car moves it moves it moves off the screen and the camera doesn't stay centered!

Comment: Sorry for all the text! I was just thinking maybe I am oversimplifying! If i imagine the car in the corner of the bitmap then obviously drawing to draw around the centre of the car would not work as there is no more bitmap to draw with. Is the only way to overcome this problem to check all the edges and then stop drawing the  background and only move the car or is there an easier way?

Comment: Ok I have figured my problem. I can't draw at car.x because this is the world position! when car.x is near the edge that == 1560 and ofcourse this is off the bounds of the screen. So what I need to do is translate between the world coordinates and the screen (max 800). Any ideas on this?

Comment: drawMap should attempt to put the car in the center based on the world location, but needs to be bound by the edges of the bitmap (> 0, < 2000-ScreenWidth). drawCar should use the screen offset calculated in drawMap to draw the car's position relative to the current view. So you draw the car at (car.x - mapOffset.x, car.y - mapOffset.y). You'll need to update drawMap to calculate x and y a little different and store them somewhere you can access from drawCar.